# How to add SKNode on the first layer SWIFT

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I'm trying to add a SKShapeNode on the scene, but if I use this:

```
let rect = SKShapeNode(SKShapeNode(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)))
self.addChild(rect)
```

This rectangle is added on the last layer and overlaps other nodes. So, how to add it on the first level?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`zPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/zPosition) property of your `SKNode`. From the docs:

> The default value is 0.0. The positive z axis is projected toward the
>   viewer so that nodes with larger z values are closer to the viewer.
>   When a node tree is rendered, the height of each node (in absolute
>   coordinates) is calculated and then all nodes in the tree are rendered
>   from smallest z value to largest z value. If multiple nodes share the
>   same z position, those nodes are sorted so that parent nodes are drawn
>   before their children, and siblings are rendered in the order that
>   they appear in their parent’s children array. Hit-testing is processed
>   in the opposite order.
>
> The SKView class’s ignoresSiblingOrder property controls whether node sorting is enabled for nodes at the same z position.

Since you seem to want your `rect` node under your other nodes, and since the default `zPosition` is `0.0`, try setting it to `-1.0`:

```
let rect = SKShapeNode(SKShapeNode(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)))
rect.zPosition = -1.0
self.addChild(rect)
```